# Spring WebFlux Mono.block() is not returning any response even no time out occured

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

there i had tried to get a Mono from my repository of Mongo. But my debugger is lost after receiving the response from repo as Mono object and applied block() to it.

HERE IS THE DETAILED CODE...

```
private Map<String, Object> parameters(Bid bid,String tripId) {
    final Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    ShipperLoad shipperLoad = (ShipperLoad)bid.getLoad();

    // getting supplier data from other service..
    SupplierUserDTO supplier =
            WebClient.
                    create("http://localhost:8888/XXXXXXXX/"+bid.getSupplierId())
                    .get()
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(SupplierUserDTO.class)
                    .block();

    TripInvoiceDetails tripInvoice = bidService.getInvoiceDetails(tripId).block();

    parameters.put("load", shipperLoad);
    parameters.put("bid", bid);
    parameters.put("logo", getClass().getResourceAsStream(logo_path));
    parameters.put("supplier", supplier);
    parameters.put("invoice", tripInvoice);

    return parameters;
}
```

Bid service method:

```
public Mono<TripInvoiceDetails> getInvoiceDetails(String tripId)
{
    Mono<TripInvoiceDetails> invoice = tripInvoiceRepository.findByTripId(tripId);
    return invoice;
}
```

Repository

```
public interface TripInvoiceRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<TripInvoiceDetails, String>{
    Mono<TripInvoiceDetails> findByTripId(String tripId);
}
```

The control is lossing on bidService.getInvoiceDetails(tripId).block();

```
TripInvoiceDetails.java
@Data
@Document("tripInvoice")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TripInvoiceDetails {
@Id
String id;
String invoiceNo;
Double invoiceamount;
Double invoiceamountGst;
ValueLabel packageType;
Integer noOfUnits;
ValueLabel materialType;
List<ValueLabel> materialTypeSecondary;
String hsnCode;
String consigneeName;
String address;
String gstOrPan;
String tripId;
String transporterId;
String shipperName;
String loadId;

}
```

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHzTw.png)

Resolved

```
try {
        //pls don't remove futureData since. it is required to resolve futureData of Mono..
        CompletableFuture<TripInvoiceDetails>  futureData = tripInvoice.toFuture();
        invoice = tripInvoice.toFuture().get();
    } catch (Exception  e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: How long did you wait? Maybe default timeout is very high.

Comment: Hi, i left the call in progress up to 1 hrs. and after no response, i force fully terminate it.

Comment: i am adding screen shot here.. no console log or error logged there.please refer added logs

Comment: Thanks a lot, issue resolved, when i breaks. block() statement into


please see attached code snippet..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your valuable response. Finally, I got a solution, I just break the .bock() method into steps, which means the did the exact implementation of the .block() method instead of calling .block() it works for me, maybe the block in the earlier case is waiting for any producer which may be in this case not marked as a producer.

```
try {
    //pls don't remove futureData since. it is required to resolve futureData of Mono..
    CompletableFuture<TripInvoiceDetails>  futureData = tripInvoice.toFuture();
    invoice = tripInvoice.toFuture().get();
} catch (Exception  e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```